# Power BI - Oracle table different names in pre and prod

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I am importing oracle table in power BI. Table has different schema in Pre and Pro Environment of Oracle DB. Also Tables have different names
Pre - sales
Pro - saLes

Now as I understand Oracle is not case sensitive. When I import table from pre using dynamic parameters and publish it into PBI service, it refreshes. I have schema parameters defined as well.
But when we change the parameters in PBI service to pro and
try to refresh then it fails with error- Key does not match any row in the table.
Table surely has data in Pro
DB. So I think its because tables are named differently?

Please can someone help in this.
Thanks,
AP

Mentioned what I have dine so far.

Comment: `Key does not match any row in the table`. The data you're looking for is not there. This has *nothing* to do with naming; an invalid name would throw a different error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will investigate further.